# Отсортировать многомерный массив

Tags: php

Есть массив вида:

```
[Акушер-гинеколог] => Array
   (
     [0] => 1600
     [2] => 1500
     [4] => 1200
   )
```

Как правильно его отсортировать по цене по возрастанию?
Использовал: 
array_multisort, asort, arsort, krsort, ksort

Comment: `sort($data['акушер-гинеколог'])` ?

Comment: если пишите, что что-то использовали, то указываете в вопросе Ваш код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может Вам такой вариант подойдет:

```
$ar = [
    'Акушер-гинеколог1'=> [ 
        0 => 1600, 
        2 => 1500,
        4 => 1200],
    'Акушер-гинеколог2'=> [   
        0 => 1600, 
        2 => 1500,
        4 => 1200]
      ];
array_multisort($ar['Акушер-гинеколог1'], SORT_ASC, 
                $ar['Акушер-гинеколог2'], SORT_ASC);
print_r($ar);
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае пробуем вот так, правильно ли я понял, что массив может выглядеть так? Пример работы https://repl.it/NpX9/1

```
$array = [
  'акушер' => [
      0 => 1600,
      2 => 1500,
      4 => 1200
    ],
  'гинеколог' => [
      0 => 1700,
      2 => 1100,
      4 => 1200
    ],
  'акушер2' => [
      0 => 1300,
      2 => 1700,
      4 => 1000
    ],
];

//можно отсортировать по ключу
ksort($array);
//сортируем внутренность
foreach ($array as $k=>$v){
  asort($array[$k]);
}

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нет связи между значениями разных веток(каждую нужно сортировать отдельно), то проще всего так и сделать:

```
$data = [
  'k1' => [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
  'k2' => [9, 8, 7, 6, 5],
];

foreach ($data as $k => $row) sort($data[$k]);

var_dump($data);
```

---

*Если эти данные поступают из базы данных, то лучше сортировать их на стороне базы.*